# How to get the following output in C programming

Tags: c, conditional-statements

A logical question asked in the aptitude test.

```
if(______)
{
 printf("Hi");
}
else
{
 printf("Hello");
}
```

What condition should be provided in place of ***_*____** to get the following output ?

```
HelloHello
```

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to give control to `else` twice. All you need is a `false` condition with a side effect of printing the other `"Hello"`, for example

```
if (printf("Hello") == 0) // this condition is false, because printf returns the number of chars written
{
    printf("Hi");
}
else
{
    printf("Hello");
}
```